# How to add two custom cells in tableview at once click on button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have tableview in which i have created three different custom cells like below :

> TableviewCell1 *cell1; 
>   TableviewCell2 *cell2;
>   TableviewCell3 *cell3;

It works fine but I need to add two custom cell like

> TableviewCell1 *cell1; 
>   TableviewCell2 *cell2;

both are at once added to tableview when add button clicked.

Any responses will be appreciated...

Comment: ok So write Button Action. we will Modify it. :)

Comment: add some code .

Comment: register custom cells in storybaord use bool variable to for checking in cellforrowatindexpath , intially it should be false on click of add button make it true and reload tablview you cell will be added . Before that array count should increased

Comment: You need to supply more details and explain what you have tried.